# Cassette Compatibility Issues

Tags: frames, bmx, new-bicycle-assembly, upgrade-or-new-bike

Because I sit at home playing games in [doodle jump](https://doodlejumping.com) too much, I decided to buy a bicycle to exercise.

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid this is a bit _too_ unspecific to help you out. To be able to, what kind of riding/exercise you want to do? Are you looking for a flat bar fitness bike, do you want to do some touring (possibly an e-bike), mountain biking or road cycling (is the _bmx_ tag intentional?). Please note that one of the platform's rules is "no shopping advice" but we can of course assist in your decision-making if you can feed in a few more details, ideally by using the _Edit_ function to update your question.

Comment: Can you please give us more information?  Location and indication of budget would help. What kind of riding - will you only ride smooth roads, maybe cycle trails, gravel road, or are you looking at mountain biking etc.  Don't spend all your money on the bike - you will need a helmet, maybe cycle clothing. water bottles etc (can make do with what you have  on some things, on otehrs its not worth it.). Also budget for repairs (DIY can be a lot cheaper).

Answer (score 2):

More so than in years past, bicycles have developed a wide variety of specialization based on how they're going to be used. Certainly it's true that you can ride a mountain bike on the road and road bike on (smooth) mountain paths, performance and comfort will suffer.  I'm not saying that you must have the perfect bike for where you ride nor that you're limited to riding only areas your bike is specifically designed for.  It is a good idea as you begin shopping for a bike to have some ideas where and how you would like to ride the bike.

Many bike shops or other businesses offer bike rentals. Your friends who may have bicycles can also be sources of bikes to get significant time test riding different styles of bikes on a variety of surfaces. Even if you have already determined the where and how you're going to bike, renting or borrowing a bike is wise to get a sense of the variables involved in selecting a bike and where to ride it.

Among to wide variety of bicycles on offer is a segment sometimes termed "cross-over" or "all sport."  A good "all-rounder" is a bike designed for use on a variety of surfaces and conditions. They typically feature straight bars, multiple gears and tires of medium width having a variety of tread patterns to handle multiple surfaces. These might be a good place to start exploring bikes and bicycling.